# About dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

My laptop's processor is a Intel Core-i3 (2.00 Ghz), 4 GB ram and 1TB HDD. I want to dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with my currently installed windows 10.

- Will it slow down my laptop?
- Will the both OS use the full 4 GB ram each?

Answer (score 0):

With dual boot you will use only one OS at a time.

It will not slow down your Windows.

Both OS's will use the full RAM.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not slow down your laptop, instead it will affect your laptop storage space. So nothing to worry about speed...

Another thing to mention is, each operating system surely will use all the available RAM. Since they (Windows and Linux) do not share hardware resources.